# CSS - Formatting a menu bar to fit the same length as the logo bar

Tags: html, css

so im making a nav bar and i would like it to fit under my logo with the same width however the nav bar seems to be shorter in width compared to the logo there making it look funny

here is the css for the logo bar:

Comment: please add html code also and create a working code snippet of your code

Comment: i have now xenio!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but they seem to be the same `width` you just need to change the background color on the `div` holding the links. Also I notice you have the `navbar` `overflow:hidden`. You should look into responsive menus: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp

```html
        <html>
                <head>
    <style type="text/css">


                .logo {
                  overflow: hidden;
                  text-align: left;
                  position: relative;
                  margin : 0px 100px ;
                  height : 60px ;
                  background-color: red;
                  color:#1F6C8B;
                  font-family: Arial;
                }

                .topnav {
                  overflow: hidden;
                  text-align: center;
                  position: relative;
                  margin : 0px 100px ;
                  height : 50px ;
                  font-family: Arial;
                  background-color: #1F6C8B;
                }

                .topnav a {
                  float: left;
                  color: #f2f2f2;
                  text-align: center;
                  padding: 10px 20px;
                  text-decoration: none;
                  font-size: 20px;
                  background-color: #1F6C8B;
                  height : 25px ;
                }

 </style>
 </head>
                <body>    
                <ul>
                        <div class="logo"><h1>logo</h1></div>
                        <div class="topnav">
                            <a href="#">HOME</a>
                            <a href="#">x</a>
                            <a href="#">y</a>
                            <a href="#">z</a>
                            <a href="#">w</a>
                            <a href="#">p</a>
                            <a href="#">n</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="minibar"><h3>Sfdgdg</h3></div>
                        <div class="mainbox"></div>
                    </ul>
                </body>
                </html>
```